# Check if page is embeded

Tags: embed, query-string, iframe

I'm trying to make condition that checks if the page is embeded with iFrame, but all the ways I know won't work. I'm embeding Woocommerce single product page, on custom template where only necessary scripts and styles are loaded (template is loaded depending on string query).

The problem is that, I want to change "add to cart" message only when the certain query string exists. `if(isset($_GET['embed_act'])) {}` doesn't work, and `get_permalink()` returns empty string.

Does anyone know how to check existence of query string or at least if the page is loaded in iframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server doesn't know what the client is doing with the output and as such, you're limited in what you can assume. You may or may not have params sent in the request, referer, current uri and headers.

- `$_REQUEST['embed_act']`
- `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`
- `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`
- `get_headers()`

On the JS side, it might be [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4594531/5623301).

```
if(self==top)
{
    //...
}

if( parent==top )
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: I just checked for string in `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` . Thank you!